# Audio from Video inside Popout automatically plays on Page Load Wordpress Elementor

Tags: wordpress, html5-video, elementor

I want to implement a popout with a video in my WordPress website using Elementor Pro plugin. The issue is that the audio from the video is automatically playing when the page loads instead of just playing when the user clicks on the play button that displays the video.

I implemented the video using HTMl and added "autoplay" as an attribute

```
<video id="video-hero" controls  
  allowFullScreen
  webkitallowfullscreen
  mozallowfullscreen
  autoplay="true"
  
 poster="https://webtroniclabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/WL-video-thumbnail.png"
 >
  <source src="https://storage.ybox.dev/wl-master-4k-compressed.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  
<track
    label="English"
    kind="subtitles"
    srclang="en"
    src="https://webtroniclabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/VEED-subtitles_Webtronic-Labs-Master-Final-4K.vtt"
    default />
</video>
```

I tried setting the popout to only display when buttons with specifics ids were clicked but didn't work [image]

Comment: Either remove `autoplay="true"` (now is always paused until user clicks "play" button)... Or else, keep it as _true_ but also add `muted="muted"` (now is auto-playing but with no sound until user clicks the sound icon in the player interface)